# Making the user give a boolean input with while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean, cin

I have just started learning C++ and trying to learn the syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    bool answer;
    cout << "Did you enjoy testing this program? (1 for yes, 0 for no) ";
    cin >> answer;
    while (!(cin >> answer)) {
        cout << "Invalid value!\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please type either 0 or 1: ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    cout << "Your feedback has been registered. Feedback: " << answer;
}
```

The aim is to keep making the user ask over and over until they input either 0 or 1. The code snippet just makes things freeze when either of those values is given. How should this be fixed?

Comment: You're waiting for the user to enter the value twice for every one time you are prompting them.

Comment: It might he worth pointing out that requiring a _human_ to be present is almost always the wrong thing to do. Bad input should mean immediate termination with error message and error code.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: I agree that especially on POSIX-based operating systems, programs should generally be designed to accept input not only from humans, but also from other programs. However, I see nothing wrong with a program also having an interactive mode which is designed for human input and which allows a human to correct his mistakes by retyping input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cin >> answer;` statement above the loop, and the `cin >> answer;` statement at the end of the loop body, both need to be removed.

You are prompting the user to enter a value, then you read in that value **and ignore it**, and then you **wait for the user to enter in another value**, even though you didn't prompt the user to enter more than 1 value.

If they do happen to enter a 2nd value, and it fails, your loop will then prompt the user to enter in a new value, then you read in that value **and ignore it**, and then you **wait for the user to enter yet another value** without prompting the user to do so.

You should be invoking `cin >> answer` only 1 time per loop iteration, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool answer;
    cout << "Did you enjoy testing this program? (1 for yes, 0 for no) ";
    // cin >> answer; // <- remove this!
    while (!(cin >> answer)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid value!\n";
        cout << "Please type either 0 or 1: ";
        // cin >> answer; // <- remove this!
    }
    cout << "Your feedback has been registered. Feedback: " << answer;
}
```